# Import a CSV file and convert it into a table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import a CSV file and convert it into a table.

My code imports the CSV and displays the data once I hit the button.

When attempting to convert the contents to a table, I receive an error:

> A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells or another table.

I don't believe there are any existing tables.

```vb
Sub ImportAssets()
    Dim csvFile As Variant
    csvFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")
    If csvFile = False Then Exit Sub
    
    'Import the data into an existing sheet
    Dim importSheet As Worksheet
    Set importSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Asset Tool")
    
    'Delete any existing tables or PivotTables in the worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    For Each tbl In importSheet.ListObjects
        tbl.Delete
    Next tbl
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In importSheet.PivotTables
        pt.TableRange2.Clear
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
    
    With importSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & csvFile, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1))
        .Name = "Imported CSV Data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ""
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1) 'Change the number of columns and the data type for each column as necessary
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    
    'Insert the data into a table
    Dim importRange As Range
    Set importRange = importSheet.UsedRange
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = importSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, importRange, , xlYes)
    table.Name = "AssetData"
    table.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have just created a query table so you cannot create a structured Excel table using the query table's range. You could use a different way to import the data. I need to know the name of `Activesheet` (the one that has the file path in `A5`) and if your file has more than 3 columns and you just want 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, you cannot convert a range that contains a query result into a Table.  However, if you don't need to maintain the workbook connection, you can convert your range into a Table by deleting the QueryTable after importing the file...

```
With importSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & csvFile, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1))
    .Name = "Imported CSV Data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ""
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1) 'Change the number of columns and the data type for each column as necessary
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .Delete
End With
```

Comment: Hi, I still receive the same error as before. Any ideas what else could be causing the issue?

Comment: I tested the code before posting it, and it ran successfully on my version of Excel, which is Excel 365.

Comment: Have you tried using the code within a brand new workbook?

Comment: You are right mate, your way worked once I created a new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by using the Macro function to check what could be missing. Had to add some random specific code and it now works for my project.

```
Sub ImportAssets()
    Dim csvFile As Variant
    csvFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")
    If csvFile = False Then Exit Sub
    
    'Import the data into an existing sheet
    Dim importSheet As Worksheet
    Set importSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Asset Tool")
    
    With importSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & csvFile, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1))
        .Name = "Imported CSV Data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ""
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1) 'Change the number of columns and the data type for each column as necessary
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    
    ' Create Table
    Dim pq As Object
    For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    If qt.Refreshing Then qt.CancelRefresh
    pq.Delete
    Next
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables("Imported_CSV_Data_8").Delete

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = importSheet.Cells(importSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Set tableRange = importSheet.Range("A5:F" & lastRow)
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tableRange, , xlYes).Name = "Table9"
    Range("Table9[#All]").Select
    
End Sub
```

Thank you everyone for attempting to resolve this for me.